# Dedicated Elasticsearch ingest (coordinate ) nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch is it recommended to have ingest nodes as dedicated? I'm planning to run Elasticsearch on k8s cluster and allowing ingest pods to be scheduled on worker nodes which have other java service pods also running. Is this good setup for production ? Any guideline how much memory, cpu should be kept for ingest nodes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your use case if you have a write-heavy system with costly transformation, then you can use the dedicated ingest node(Note this is different from the co-ordinate node, the title of question is misleading).

Please refer [different node type in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#modules-node) and please refer the [responsibility of coordinating node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-node)

**As explained in the official doc of nodes**

> Ingest nodes are able to apply an ingest pipeline to a document in
>   order to transform and enrich the document before indexing. With a
>   heavy ingest load, it makes sense to use dedicated ingest nodes and to
>   mark the master and data nodes as node.ingest: false.